# dojo i want to know same function that jquery $(document).ready() in dojo

Tags: dojo

I have to perform some functions before load a html Page. jquery's $ (document). ready () is executed before the html Page be loaded. But I do not know that dojo have same function. Please advise me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear to me, when you write:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Then that code is only executed **after** the page is loaded + rendered and not before (like you said).

That being said, Dojo has a similar module called `dojo/domReady!`. You can use it in two ways, for example:

```js
require([ "dojo/domReady!" ], function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Now the code is only being executed after the page is loaded + rendered (just like the jQuery `.ready()` function).

If you also want to wait until all widgets are parsed, then you have to use the `dojo/ready`  module:

```js
require([ "dojo/ready" ], function(ready) {
    ready(function() {
        // Your code
    });
});
```

Now that code is only executed after the page is loaded + rendered and if `parseOnLoad` is enabled, it will also wait until all declarative widgets on that page are parsed.

More information can be found in the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/domReady.html).